# Change Orientation while converting android handset app to tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I am converting and android handset application to tablet (1024*600 and 1280*720). I have given the support for different screen- size, but stuck in orientation part. I want some pages  to be visible as landscape. For example after logged in by user the next intent should be in landscape form. After searching I found clue but not very understandable answer such as

1. By adding activity in manifest.xml file
2. At runtime by using getOrientation().

Thanks

Comment: try to set like setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); on the activity where ever you need landscape.

Comment: "I want some pages to be visible as landscape". What if the screen is in portrait mode?

Comment: I did this by adding activity in manifest.xml file. But I am wondering if it will work when auto-rotation mode is enable. I think it will work but will look bad. Could you make me clear.

Comment: Have you set in your layout for example `layout-sw600dp-land` or `layout-large-land`? If screenOrientation is `"unspecified"` that means the orientation can change automatic from the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear, if you're forcing screen orientation by size (e.g. on tablet device there's only landscape orientation), i think you should get the screen width and height first then evaluate it. If the screen width and height are 1024*600 or 1280*720, you change the orientation with `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

To get the width and height, do this in your activity:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width, height;
try {
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
}
catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
    width = display.getWidth();
    height = display.getHeight();
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Comment: I think checking width and height is not needed, setting layout-sw600dp-land or layout-large-land is enough as android automatically sense it and display the respective data accordingly.BTW thanks for help.